# Write a code that Calculates the average number of non-zero ratings per individual in our data set

Tags: python, debugging

So I've written my code below but I am having a hard time getting the code to not include the number of zeros. It runs but unfortunately not the way I want it to. Can anyone shed some light?

*the variable movies is basically a list of movies we were given*  The code will be right if an average of 21.4 is the output.

```
all_ratings =[
[5,5,4,4,3,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,4,1,4,0,0,0,1,2,5],  
[5,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,4,2,1,0,1,2,0,5,0,4,1,4,2,0,0,1,0,5],  
[5,2,3,4,4,0,0,0,4,5,0,3,0,0,0,3,4,0,1,4,4,4,0,4,0,3,0,1,2,5],  
[5,0,4,0,0,4,2,3,0,0,4,0,3,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,1,5],  
[5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,0,3,0,1,2,4,4,4,4,1,4,0,0,0,1,2,5],  
]


total=[]
average=[]

for index in range (len(all_ratings)):
    total+=[sum(all_ratings[index])]

for index in range(len(all_ratings)):
    average = average + [total[index]/30]

for index in range(len(movies)):
    print(average)
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to take the average of each row excluding the 0's. these ratings are from 5 friends who rated 30 movies

Comment: I am to take the average of each person's rating in each row excluding 0 entries. does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

define

```
def mean(l):
    return sum(l)/len(l)
```

and now

```
[mean([y for y in x if y > 0]) for x in allratings]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might be a solution.

```
all_ratings =[
[5,5,4,4,3,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,4,1,4,0,0,0,1,2,5],  
[5,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,4,2,1,0,1,2,0,5,0,4,1,4,2,0,0,1,0,5],  
[5,2,3,4,4,0,0,0,4,5,0,3,0,0,0,3,4,0,1,4,4,4,0,4,0,3,0,1,2,5],  
[5,0,4,0,0,4,2,3,0,0,4,0,3,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,1,5],  
[5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,0,3,0,1,2,4,4,4,4,1,4,0,0,0,1,2,5],  
]

def get_average(vals): # without zero
    counter = 0 
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        if (vals[i] != 0):
            counter += 1
        total += vals[i]
    return round(total / counter, 2)

for i in range(len(all_ratings)):
    print(get_average(all_ratings[i]))
```

Update: I guess 21.4 would be the average number of movies that were rated in each list of ratings. The code below returns `21.4`

```
counter = 0;

for index, item in np.ndenumerate(all_ratings):
    if item != 0:
        counter += 1

print(counter / 5)
```

Comment: unfortunately not! I've been on this question for hours now and not quite sure ow to solve it. but thanks for the attempt.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would suggest calculating the averages by hand. That way you know the code is doing the proper calculations when the two answers meet.

Comment: Looking at your post. I'm not sure where you're getting 21.4. The average for each line can't be higher than 5 and the average of all the averages can't be higher than whatever the largest average is. Meaning an average of the averages won't be larger than 5. Now if you're simply summing each list and then dividing by 5, to find the average sum of all the lists your excluding of the zeros wouldn't then matter. And I got 65.4 when I did that.

Comment: I just figured it out.its taken by counting the movie. so there's 30 movies. each movie is counted as 1. you only count movies with a rating of greater than 0 to them. I did the math by hand and indeed it is correct. 21.4 107/5=21.4 which I got

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy array to select nonzero elements and numpy mean to get the average

```
from numpy import array, mean

answ = [mean(array(el)[array(el)!=0]) for el in 
all_ratings]

print (answ)
```

Output:

```
[3.2083333333333335, 2.869565217391304, 3.4210526315789473, 2.8125, 2.96]
```